# swiftUI: I can't jump to another view

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here is my code which describe a Login System, using SwiftData.And I promise there is no problem in SwiftData part.I can see alert clearly but when I tap "OK" in Login alert, it doesn't jump.
[some details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXxLM.png)

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct LoginView: View {
    
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query private var userInfo: [User]
    @State private var stuid = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var LoginIn = false
    
    enum myAlert {
        case Login
        case error
        case noinput
    }
    @State private var alertType: myAlert? = nil
    @State private var showAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "road.lanes.curved.right")
                        .font(.title)
                    Text("登录")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding()
                TextField("学号", text: $stuid)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
                    .border(.black, width: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                SecureField("密码", text: $password)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.05))
                    .border(.black, width: 2)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                Button("Login") {
                    showAlert.toggle()
                    authenticateUser(stuid: stuid, password: password)
                }
                .alert(isPresented: $showAlert, content: {
                    getAlert()
                })
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
                .background(Color.black)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                .padding()
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .navigationDestination(isPresented: $LoginIn) {
            MainMenu()
        }
    }
    func authenticateUser(stuid: String, password: String) {
        
        if stuid == "" || password == "" {
            alertType = .noinput
        }
        
        var flag = false
        for user in userInfo {
            if stuid == user.stuId && password == user.password {
                flag = true
                alertType = .Login
            }
        }
        if !flag {
            alertType = .error
        }
    }
    
    func getAlert() -> Alert {
        switch alertType {
        case .Login:
            return Alert(
            title: Text("登录成功"),
            primaryButton: .default(Text("OK"), action: {
                LoginIn = true
                print(LoginIn)
            }),
            secondaryButton: .cancel())
        case .noinput:
            return Alert(title: Text("请输入您的学号和密码"))
        case .error:
            return Alert(title: Text("学号或密码错误"))
        default:
            return Alert(title: Text("ERROR"))
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

I check the view, there is no problem in the view I want to jump to.And I also print ***LoginIn*** after alert.it is true.So I don't know why it doesn't jump.

Comment: try moving the `.navigationDestination(...)` inside the `NavigationStack`